# How to manually append a character after chapter counter?

Tags: chapters, counters

`book` does not have `\addtodef{\afterchapternum}{課}{}` that is available in `memoir`. As a result, I have to manually append it. But how? I don't want to use `memoir`.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{ipaexm.ttf}
\setmainfont{Cambria}


\renewcommand\chaptername{第}
%\addtodef{\afterchapternum}{課}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{手引}
おはようございます！



\end{document}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thechapter}` is perhaps not what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This defines a `\afterchapnum` macro and uses it, if it is defined in `\makechapterhead` command right after `\thechapter`.

Redefining `\thechapter` is perhaps not useful, since this would appear in the `ToC` and potential references too.

(Sorry, had to comment all CJK stuff)

The code could be shortened by patching (but that requires another package, either `etoolbox` or `xpatch`)

```
\documentclass{book}

%\usepackage{xeCJK}
%\setCJKmainfont{ipaexm.ttf}
%\setmainfont{Cambria}


%\renewcommand\chaptername{第}
%\addtodef{\afterchapternum}{課}{}

\newcommand{\afterchapternum}{Foo}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter~\@ifundefined{afterchapternum}{}{\afterchapternum}%
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
%\chapter{手引}
%おはようございます！



\end{document}
```

**Update** with `\xpatchcmd`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xpatch}


\newcommand{\afterchapternum}{FooBar}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{%
\thechapter%
% look for `\thechapter` only -- it's unique in `\@makechapterhead, so this is 'safe'
}{% Replace it by this: 
\thechapter~\@ifundefined{afterchapternum}{}{\afterchapternum}%
}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failure!}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you also provide the patching trick?

Comment: @YasashiiEirian: See the update at the bottom!

Comment: In my document I have load `etoolbox`, could you also provide the solution with this package such that I don't need to load `xpatch` package?

Comment: @YasashiiEirian: Why did you not say this before? It would make helping easier, much easier, not changing the question from step to step. And the solution is Change `\xpatchcmd` to `\patchcmd` ;-))  `xpatch` uses `etoolbox` anyway ;-)

Comment: I am sorry. Sometimes I lost my consciousness.

Comment: @YasashiiEirian: I hope you awake from those states then again ;-)